# div aligned left with fixed and another div with 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make a div align with the left fixed. And I want another div to take 100% of the size restante.quero make a div align with the left fixed. And I want another div to take 100% of the remaining size.

However, the second div always goes down, but the second div always goes down.

How to do this? How to do this?

Demo em jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jxt4V/1/

```
.coluna2
{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;    
    float : left;        
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your following  css to this: (`#principal` and `.coluna2`)

```
#principal 
{
    width:100%;
    background:#babaca; 
    float : left;   
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position:relative;   /* adding Position: relative; here */   
}



.coluna2
{
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:150px;   /* giving the value of the adjacent element ie width: 150px */
    bottom:0;
    right:0;        
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxt4V/2/)**

Comment: Or get rid of positioning and use margin-left instead.

Comment: @joeframbach never done that. Can you show me how? (maybe post here as answer)

Comment: n tests. was a problem. If the contents of the "" is greater than the footer, the footer is at the bottom of the page and the text goes over.

As this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jxt4V/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/joeframbach/YLCLZ/

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
div {
    margin-left: 120px;
}

<img src="http://www.poundland.co.uk/images/4414/original/filler-2.jpg" />
<div>This text is on the right</div>
<div>This is also on the right</div>
```